# How to regexextract link texts from a block of html text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a block of html text from which I need to extract the link texts. The HTML code is

```
<li><span class="jkey-title">Job Field</span> <span class="jkey-info"><a href="/jobs-by-field/agriculture">Agriculture / Agro-Allied</a>&nbsp; , <a href="/jobs-by-field/ngo">NGO/Non-Profit</a>&nbsp; , <a href="/jobs-by-field/project-management">Project Management</a>&nbsp;</span> </li>
```

What I need is the individual link texts separated by a comma and non-breaking space:
Like this:

`Agriculture/Agro-Allied, &nbsp; NGO/Non-Profit, &nbsp; Project Management`

Here's a link to my spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13R-TyBMDc64iocSb7LFNM7np7KMo8icDHKnk-E_kvIo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your sample input value, it's `Agriculture / Agro-Allied` But, in your sample output value, `Agriculture/Agro-Allied`. In your sample output value, do you want to remove the space from the output value? And, in your sample input value, the delimiter is ``&nbsp; , ``. But in your sample output value, the delimiter is ``, &nbsp; ``. I cannot understand the logic for achieving this from your sample input value. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving your expected value? By the way, your sample input value is retrieved from an URL, xpath might be able to be used. How about this?

Comment: Just replace all matches of `<[^<>]+?>` with an empty string in your HTML.